# UICollectionView query

Tags: ios, ui-automation, calabash, calabash-ios

Calabash ios has the each_cell method to perform an action on each cell of a table.

```
each_cell(:query => "tableView", :animate => false, :post_scroll => 0.1) do |row, sec|
touch("tableViewCell indexPath:#{row},#{sec}")
tap "back_button"
end
```

I got a collection view, then I tried to use the same code

```
each_cell(:query => "collectionView", :animate => false, :post_scroll => 0.1) do |row, sec|
touch("collectionViewCell indexPath:#{row},#{sec}")
tap "back_button"
end
```

But it wasn't working and got this error:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `times' for "*****":String

So I reckon this function could be limited to only cater table views? Any idea on how to perform action on each cell on collection view? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

what i did was...

1. Create a function called `each_item` similar to `each`

   ```
   def each_item(opts={:query => 'UICollectionView', :post_scroll => 2, :animate => true}, &block)
     uiquery = opts[:query] || 'UICollectionView'
     check_element_exists(uiquery)
     secs = query(uiquery,:numberOfSections).first
     secs.times do |sec|
       items = query(uiquery,{:numberOfItemsInSection => sec}).first
       items.times do |item_pos|
         scroll_to_collection_view_item(item_pos, sec, opts)
         sleep(opts[:post_scroll]) if opts[:post_scroll] and opts[:post_scroll] > 0
        yield(item_pos, sec)
       end
     end
   end
   ```
2. To Use this, you can do something like this

   ```
   each_item do |item_pos, section_number|
     # YOUR CODE HERE
     # to use the query with collection view item
     # query("<HERE USE YOUR CUSTOM CLASS OF THE ITEMS IN THE CELLS> indexPath:#{item_pos},#{section_number}")
   end
   ```

Comment: And so, what is the question ?